# How to fix sonar plugin issue in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

How to avoid issue with sonar scanner plugin on Jenkins 2.289.2, plugin sonar 2.13.1
when compiling a project I got the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar (default-cli) on project maven-project: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar failed: 
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

It looks like an issue with the version of java but I would like to avoid changing my java version

Comment: What is the default java version ?

Comment: The SonarScanner works only with Java 11. You may use Java 8 to compile/test/etc the code, but the scan must be done with Java 11. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66267806/4944847

Comment: did my answer solved your issue maybe ?

Answer (score 7):

Probably the compiled code you trying to run was compiled using java 11, but in env installed only java 8.

Try to install **java 11** and make sure to update OS environment settings to point to the new JDK.

Java Details:

- Java 8 uses major version 52
- Java 11 uses major version 55