# Scanning Java 8 Spring boot project for sonarqube using sonar gradle plugin but it require java 11

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

My project is using java 8 and sonarqube plugin `id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.6.2'`. When I build project using command `./gradlew clean build`, it builds fine.

but when I try to run `./gradlew sonarqube`, I get error

```sh
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent
version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

My sonarqube task looks like something

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.analysis.mode"]   = "publish"
        properties["sonar.projectKey"]      = System.getenv("SONAR_PROJECT_KEY").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.projectName"]     = System.getenv("SONAR_PROJECT_NAME").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.host.url"]        = System.getenv("SONAR_HOST").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.login"]           = System.getenv("SONAR_TOKEN").toString().trim()
        properties["sonar.branch.name"]     = System.getenv("CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME").toString().trim()
        switch(System.getenv("CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME").toString().trim()) {
            case ~/^feature\/MDS-.*$/:
                properties["sonar.branch.target"] = "develop"
            break
            case 'master':
            case 'develop':
            break
            default:
                properties["sonar.branch.target"] = "master"
            break
        }
        properties["sonar.exclusions"]              = "**/analytics/model/**/*.java"
        properties["sonar.coverage.exclusions"]     = "**/analytics/model/**/*.java"
    }
}
```

### What I tried

I tried this answer [Run SonarScanner analysis with Java 11, run target code with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267806/run-sonarscanner-analysis-with-java-11-run-target-code-with-java-8)

```sh
# build successful
 ./gradlew clean build

# change to java 11
 $env:JAVA_HOME="C:\Users\wv3cxq\Downloads\jdk-11.0.12_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11.0.12"

# Tried to run sonarqube task
./gradlew sonarqube
```

Then getting following error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
```

## Edit

My company uses gitlab runner and with openjdk 8, sonarqube is working fine. I don't know how? I am attaching dockerfile also. May be someone will understant why it is working there and not on my machine.

**I removed some sensitive part**

```
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/

RUN apk --no-cache update   && \
    apk --no-cache add      \
      openjdk8=8.171.11-r0  \
      docker=17.12.1-r0     \
    && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install docker-compose==1.22.0 awsebcli==3.7.8 && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["sh"]
```

Comment: Java 8 went end of support January 2019, and the current version is 17! For *lots* of good reasons, you should upgrade your java version.

Comment: Instead of just setting $JAVA_HOME at that point, try adding $JAVA_HOME/bin to the head of the PATH.

Comment: @bohemian, actually, [Oracle announced](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3532358/oracle-extends-extended-support-for-java-8.html) extended support for JDK8 to [at least Dec 2030](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html) and OpenJDK has support to [at least May 2026](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html). Due to widespread corporate use, it will outlive 11 and maybe 17! Anything in between (I'm non-lts) is now deprecated and EOL.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem because I encounter the same thing

Comment: @dna still not.

Comment: I am now using `sonarqube:lts` docker image and it is working. It just gives a warning but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the latest sonarqube which requires Java 11. I switched to Sonarqube 8 and now the only warning is coming.

[image]

If you are using docker sonarqube try using `sonarqube:lts`